# WPF - why an InvalidOperationException when creating and showing a window in different worker threads?

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

Before I start, I need to preface this by stating that this code and the mechanisms are legacy code in a HUGE software product that is in the final stages of a complete migration from WinForms to WPF. The code and practices are archaic, however, due to resource and schedule constraints, it is necessary to use these archaic practice and make them work somehow for now.

In our WPF application, I have an "action" class object with an *Execute()* method that is called on a separate thread each time. This particular "action" object simply displays either a modal or modeless window depending on the value of the *IsModal* property of the object. This application code is code that I have migrated from a legacy WinForms application.

My issue is that, the first time the window is created, I get the classic "**The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it**" exception is thrown when the Show() or ShowDialog() method is called after creating the window. I've even added a GC.Collect() call after the window closes to

Here is the code for the Execute() method:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the sequence.  Shows the given string in to the user.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            bool bActionResult = true;

            string sMessageString;
            if (!GetStringFromParm("CmiActionMessageBox", m_StringToShow, out sMessageString))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (this.ConvertEscapeSequences)
            {
                sMessageString = this.GetStringConvertEscapeSequences(sMessageString);
            }

            #region Show Message Box
            // Create the form
            UserPromptWindow frm = new UserPromptWindow(sMessageString);
            frm.SetOKButtonText(m_sOkButtonName);
            frm.SetCancelButtonText(m_sCancelButtonName);
            frm.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;

            #region Adjust Dialog based upon action properties
            bool? dr;

            if (m_bDialogIsModal)
            {
                dr = frm.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                frm.Show();

                // Wait until it goes away
                while (frm.ModelessResult == null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(50);

                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

                    if (SequenceMgr.Mgr.BgSequenceDone)
                    {
                        ModelessDialogResult = false;

                        // Close the window, if it is still open
                        if (frm.IsLoaded)
                        {
                            frm.Close();
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }

                dr = ModelessDialogResult;
            }

            // Make sure the window goes completely away
            GC.Collect();
            #endregion

            #region Save the result to variable (if needful)
            if (m_bDialogSavesResult)
            {
                if (dr == true)
                {
                    SequenceMgr.Mgr.SetVariableValue(m_sDialogResultVar, "True");
                }
                else
                {
                    SequenceMgr.Mgr.SetVariableValue(m_sDialogResultVar, "False");
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Set the action result to false if configured to stop the sequence upon hitting the cancel button
            if (m_bDialogCanStopSequence)
            {
                if (dr == false)
                {
                    bActionResult = false;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            return bActionResult;
        }
```

I've attempted to spawn another thread for creating and showing the window, but the same thing occurs.

Comment: UI elements like windows are owned by the UI thread, just the way it works. Invoking Execute that pops up a window from another thread will always result in that error. GC.Collect does nothing in your code (and shouldn't be called manually in 99% of cases) Separate long running tasks into your business layer, and use a good MVVM pattern to keep UI and logic apart. Threading becomes a non issue at that point.

Comment: Are you using threads here because you don't understand tasks and async? Cause that's the answer to your problem, plus a healthy dose of separation of concerns (UI tasks shouldn't be mixed in bussiness logic. for example).

Comment: `Thread.Sleep`, `DoEvents`, this is absolutely horrendous code. You are headed down a complete technological dead end with this.

Comment: @Bindy this is horrendous code because it was inherited.  If you could provide a way to correct it, it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @AnthonyG. this is an inherited application that is HUGE. Unfortunately, from a business standpoint, it isn't practical to rewrite this sequencing framework to use e.g. tasks. In this case, in particular, this specific action is supposed to display a message window. Thank you for your input, though.

Comment: You migrated this stuff from winforms? Winforms has thread affinity for UI. These techniques wouldn't work in winforms. How does the code you are migrating do this?

Comment: @Bindy this horrendous code was inherited.  As I mentioned to Anthony G., we don't have the luxury of rewriting all of this complex code for a worldwide product given constraints on resources and product release deadlines. The odd thing here, is that if I use the legacy WinForm version of the message window, all of this works with no problem.  If you could provide a way to correct it, it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Andy, the code did definitely work as written. This WPF window that is being created and shown was a WinForms dialog until 2 days ago and worked find.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you to those who provided feedback.

After several attempts to e.g. create and show the user prompt window in a Task, I found that the way to make it work was to run the code in the application dispatcher context. Again, this entire solution using threads is archaic and will be updated to use Tasks sometime in the future, but for now the solution that works uses a combination of *Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()* to make sure the window is created and displayed in a UI thread, and *System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,new Action(delegate { }));* to allow the window's UI to run while waiting for the window to be closed by the user, or determine that the user has cancelled (stopped) the currently executing sequence of actions.

Here is the resulting code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the sequence.  Shows the given string in to the user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override bool Execute()
    {
        bool bActionResult = true;

        string sMessageString;
        if (!GetStringFromParm("CmiActionMessageBox", m_StringToShow, out sMessageString))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (this.ConvertEscapeSequences)
        {
            sMessageString = this.GetStringConvertEscapeSequences(sMessageString);
        }

        bool? dr = ShowMessageBox(sMessageString);

        if (m_bDialogSavesResult)
        {
            if (dr == true)
            {
                SequenceMgr.Mgr.SetVariableValue(m_sDialogResultVar, "True");
            }
            else
            {
                SequenceMgr.Mgr.SetVariableValue(m_sDialogResultVar, "False");
            }
        }

        if (m_bDialogCanStopSequence)
        {
            if (dr == false)
            {
                bActionResult = false;
            }
        }

        return bActionResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the message box
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sMessageString"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool? ShowMessageBox(string sMessageString)
    {
        bool? dr = null;

        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            UserPromptWindow userPromptWindow = new UserPromptWindow(sMessageString);
            userPromptWindow.SetOKButtonText(m_sOkButtonName);
            userPromptWindow.SetCancelButtonText(m_sCancelButtonName);
            userPromptWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;

            if (m_bDialogIsModal)
            {
                dr = userPromptWindow.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    userPromptWindow.Show();

                    // Wait until it goes away
                    while (userPromptWindow.ModelessResult == null)
                    {
                        // Let the UI events run
                        GlobalMethods.WpfApplicationsDoEvents();

                        // Did the user press the stop button?
                        if (SequenceMgr.Mgr.BgSequenceDone)
                        {
                            userPromptWindow.ModelessResult = false;

                            // Close the window, if it is still open
                            if (userPromptWindow.IsLoaded)
                            {
                                userPromptWindow.Close();
                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    SystemEventsMgr.AddException("Exception in MessageBox sequence action", e);
                    userPromptWindow.ModelessResult = false;
                }

                dr = userPromptWindow.ModelessResult;
            }
        }));

        return dr;
    }
```